# merge duplicate rows in DataTable in one record and updating some columns

Tags: c#

I have a `Datatable` in my C# code

```
DataTable dtDetails;
```

My Datatable how following records;

```
id | tid | code | pNameLocal        | qty | price
-------------------------------------------------
1  |101  | 101  | some_local_name   | 2   |20.36
2  |102  | 202  | some_local_name   | 1   |15.30 // exactly same entry 
3  |102  | 202  | some_local_name   | 1   |15.30 // exactly same entry
4  |102  | 202  | some_local_name   | 1   |10.00 //same entry as same tid but price is different
5  |102  | 202  | some_local_name   | 2   |15.30 //same entry as same tid but different qty
6  |102  | 202  | some_local_name2  | 1   |15.30 //same entry as same tid but pNameLocal different
7  |103  | 202  | some_local_name   | 1   |15.30 // different entry of same product see different tid
8  |104  | 65   | some_local_name   | 5   |05.00
9  |105  | 700  | some_local_name   | 2   |07.01 // does not exist in "dtProduct"
```

what to do is records which are exactly same but entered multiple times to be merged into one, but keeping their `qty` column and `price` column updated, for example in above `DaraRows` **id 2 and 3 have exactly same record as id 1**, this should be one record and update `qty` and `price` by adding from duplicate records which are exactly same. this should update in same `DataTable` or in new.

Comment: I suggest creating a joined Primary Key, so that you get a primary key violation on double entries.

Comment: @FreekW. unfortunately I have no command over that.

Answer (score 2):

You can take the DataTable as enumarable, and use Linq to create your new DataTable. The code would look something like this:

```
    DataTable newDt = dt.AsEnumerable()
        .GroupBy(r => r.Field<int>("tid"))
        .Select(g => {
            var row = dt.NewRow();

            row["tid"] = g.Key;
            row["code"] = g.First(r => r["code"] != null).Field<int>("code");
            row["pNameLocal"] = g.First(r => r["pNameLocal"] != null).Field<string>("pNameLocal");
            row["qty"] = g.Sum(r => r.Field<int>("qty"));
            row["price"] = g.Sum(r => r.Field<double>("price"));

            return row;
        }).CopyToDataTable();
```

See sample console application below, setting up sample data, executing the grouping and displaying the original and result Datatables.

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var dt = FillUpTestTable();
        DumpDataTable(dt);
        DataTable newDt = dt.AsEnumerable()
            .GroupBy(r => r.Field<int>("tid"))
            .Select(g => {
                var row = dt.NewRow();

                row["tid"] = g.Key;
                row["code"] = g.First(r => r["code"] != null).Field<int>("code");
                row["pNameLocal"] = g.First(r => r["pNameLocal"] != null).Field<string>("pNameLocal");
                row["qty"] = g.Sum(r => r.Field<int>("qty"));
                row["price"] = g.Sum(r => r.Field<double>("price"));

                return row;
            }).CopyToDataTable();

        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Result: ");
        Console.WriteLine();

        DumpDataTable(newDt);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    private static DataTable FillUpTestTable()
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.Add("id", typeof(int));
        dt.Columns.Add("tid", typeof(int));
        dt.Columns.Add("code", typeof(int));
        dt.Columns.Add("pNameLocal", typeof(string));
        dt.Columns.Add("qty", typeof(int));
        dt.Columns.Add("price", typeof(double));

        dt.Rows.Add(1, 101, 101, "some_local_name", 2, 20.36);
        dt.Rows.Add(2, 102, 202, "some_local_name", 2, 15.30);
        dt.Rows.Add(3, 102, 202, "some_local_name", 2, 15.30);
        dt.Rows.Add(4, 102, 202, "some_local_name", 2, 10.00);
        dt.Rows.Add(5, 102, 202, "some_local_name", 2, 15.30);
        dt.Rows.Add(6, 102, 202, "some_local_name2", 1, 15.30);
        dt.Rows.Add(7, 103, 202, "some_local_name", 2, 15.30);
        dt.Rows.Add(8, 104, 202, "some_local_name", 2, 05.00);
        dt.Rows.Add(9, 105, 202, "some_local_name", 2, 07.01);

        return dt;
    }
    private static void DumpDataTable(DataTable newDt)
    {
        foreach (DataRow dataRow in newDt.Rows)
        {
            foreach (var item in dataRow.ItemArray)
            {
                Console.Write(item + "   | ");
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Nice, but one small issue, he wanted to sum "records which are exactly same", so not only the first column.

Answer (score 1):

You need like this in datatable:

```
SELECT tid, code, pNameLocal, sum(qty),sum(price) FROM @tbl
group by tid, code, pNameLocal,qty, price
```

You can use linq. Try following code. I tried to use your sample records.

```
 DataTable dt = new DataTable();

            DataColumn[] dcCol =  {
                new DataColumn("id",typeof(int)),
                new DataColumn("tid", typeof(int)),
                new DataColumn("code", typeof(int)),
                new DataColumn("pNameLocal", typeof(string)),
                new DataColumn("qty", typeof(int)),
                new DataColumn("price", typeof(decimal))
        };

            dt.Columns.AddRange(dcCol);


            dt.Rows.Add(1, 101, 101, "some_local_name", 2, 20.36);
            dt.Rows.Add(2, 102, 202, "some_local_name", 1, 10.00);
            dt.Rows.Add(3, 102, 202, "some_local_name", 1, 15.30);
            dt.Rows.Add(4, 102, 202, "some_local_name", 1, 10.00);
            dt.Rows.Add(5, 102, 202, "some_local_name", 2, 15.30);
            dt.Rows.Add(6, 102, 202, "some_local_name2", 1, 15.30);
            dt.Rows.Add(7, 103, 202, "some_local_name", 1, 15.30);
            dt.Rows.Add(8, 104, 65, "some_local_name", 5, 05.00);
            dt.Rows.Add(9, 105, 700, "some_local_name", 2, 07.01);


            var dtnew = from r in dt.AsEnumerable()
                        group r by new
                        {
                            tid = r.Field<int>("tid"),
                            code = r.Field<int>("code"),
                            pNameLocal = r.Field<string>("pNameLocal"),
                            qty = r.Field<int>("qty"),
                            price = r.Field<decimal>("price")
                        } into grp
                        select new
                        {
                            tid1 = grp.Key.tid,
                            code1 = grp.Key.code,
                            pNameLocal1 = grp.Key.pNameLocal,
                            SumQty = grp.Sum(r => grp.Key.qty),
                            sumPrice = grp.Sum(r => grp.Key.price)
                        };
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `GroupBy` on an anonymous type containing all columns apart from count and price:

```
var aggregatedRowData = dtDetails.AsEnumerable()
    .Select(r => new
    {
        tid = r.Field<int>("tid"),
        code = r.Field<int>("code"),
        pNameLocal = r.Field<string>("pNameLocal"),
        qty = r.Field<int>("qty"),
        price = r.Field<decimal>("price"),
    })
    .GroupBy(x => new { x.tid, x.code, x.pNameLocal })
    .Select(grp => new
    {
        grp.Key.tid,
        grp.Key.code,
        grp.Key.pNameLocal,
        qty = grp.Sum(x => x.qty),
        price = grp.Sum(x => x.price)
    });

DataTable aggregatedTable = dtDetails.Clone();  // empty, same columns
foreach (var x in aggregatedRowData)
    aggregatedTable.Rows.Add(x.tid, x.code, x.pNameLocal, x.qty, x.price);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what you can do If rows are to be distinct based on **ALL COLUMNS**.

```
DataTable newDatatable = dt.DefaultView.ToTable(true, "tid", "code", "pNameLocal", "qty", "price");
```

The columns you mention here, only those will be returned back in newDatatable.